# Can sqlite3 reference primary keys during a for loop?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I have a database where I have imported texts as a primary keys.
I then have columns with keywords that can pertain to the texts, for example column "arson". Each of these columns has a default value of 0.

I am trying to get the SQLite3 database to read the texts, check for the presence of specific keywords, and then assign a 1 value to the keywords column, for the row where the text contained the keyword.

The below example is of me trying to change the values in the arson column only for rows where the text contains the words "Arson".

The program is reading the texts and printing yes 3 times, indicating that three of the texts have the words "Arson" in them. However, I cannot get the individual rows to update with 1's. I have tried a few variations of the code below but seem to be stuck on this one.

```
!# Python3
#import sqlite3

sqlite_file = 'C:\\Users\\xxxx\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35-32\\database.sqlite'
conn = sqlite3.connect(sqlite_file)
c = conn.cursor()



texts = c.execute("SELECT texts FROM database")
for articles in texts:
    for words in articles:
        try:
            if "Arson" in words:
                print('yes')
                x = articles
                c.execute("UPDATE database SET arson = 1 WHERE ID = ?" (x))
        except TypeError:
            pass

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Comment: `c.execute("UPDATE database SET arson = 1 WHERE ID = ?" (x))` would raise a `TypeError` exception. Why are you trying to catch that error? You got your syntax wrong there.

Comment: `c.execute("UPDATE database SET arson = 1 WHERE ID = ?" (x))` would raise a `TypeError` exception. Why are you trying to catch that error? You got your syntax wrong there.

Comment: You are right, I removed the try except clause. It was a leftover from when I was opening all the columns in the DB and some were TEXT and others were INTEGER. I removed it and now get a TypeError - 'str' object is not callable. I don't really know what to do with this, I passed strings to c.execute to get the original texts into the db: text = str(articles)   sets = str(ordered_set(articles))      c.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO database(sets, texts) VALUES (?, ?)", (sets, text))        How do I get it to reference the articles in my for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Four hours later I have finally been able to fix this. I added the commas as recommended above; however, this led to other issues, as the code did not execute the entire loop correctly. To do this, I had to add another cursor object and use the second cursor inside my loop. The revised code may be seen below:

```
!# Python3
import sqlite3

sqlite_file = 'C:\\Users\\xxxx\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35-32\\database.sqlite'
conn = sqlite3.connect(sqlite_file)
c = conn.cursor()
c2 = conn.cursor()

atexts = c.execute("SELECT texts FROM database")
for articles in atexts:
    for words in articles:
        if "arson" in words:
           print('yes')
           c2.execute("UPDATE database SET arson = 1 WHERE texts = ?", (words,))


conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

This expression:

```
c.execute("UPDATE database SET arson = 1 WHERE ID = ?" (x))
```

**always** will raise a `TypeError`, because you are trying to treat the string as a function. You are basically doing `"..."(argument)`, as if `"..."` were callable.

You'd need to add some commas for it to be an attempt to pass in `x` as a SQL parameter:

```
c.execute("UPDATE database SET arson = 1 WHERE ID = ?", (x,))
```

The first comma separates the two arguments passed to `c.execute()`, so now you pass a query string, and a separate sequence of parameters.

The second comma makes `(..,)` a tuple with one element in it. It is the comma that matters there, although the `(...)` parentheses are still needed to disambiguate what the comma represents.

You can drop the `try...except TypeError` altogether. If the code is still raising `TypeError` exceptions, you still have a bug.

Comment: Thanks, I figured out the comma shortly after my edit time ran out. I updated the code with the comma's unfortunately, I am still getting an error which I don't understand, "sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: ID" but I checked and re-checked and arson is one of my columns.  Additionally, I've tried swapping articles with words for the x value, but get the same result.

Comment: This resolved the issue in my former comment: c.execute("UPDATE ancast SET arson = 1 WHERE texts = ?", (x,))....led to another issue, only the second row is being updated. Not the others, the 1st and the last. I will check my loop.

Comment: @DTracer: you didn't share your table columns, so I could only assume that `ID` was the correct column name. If `texts` was the correct column name to select on, then yes, that would fix the issue.